# I have an issue when using DTLSServerProtocol

Tags: java, sip, java-websocket

I am working on Sip program, the DTLSServerProtocal.accept seem to stuck forever, it did not throw exception, do you have any idea why?

Another issue is currently my InetSocketAddress is fail when create new address by using host name, can somebody help?